# Is Spring Boot going to support ActiveMQ "Classic" and ActiveMQ Artemis longterm?

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

We are migrating our application to Spring Boot 3 and according to the [changelogs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#other-removals) ActiveMQ "Classic" was deprecated and later in the [release notes of Spring Boot 3.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.1-Release-Notes#activemq-support) it was recovered except for the embedded broker.

Is Spring going to support ActiveMQ "Classic" or is there a tendency towards ActiveMQ Artemis? This information would be helpful to decide if we want to remove ActiveMQ "Classic" in favor of Artemis which already supports the Jakarta migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ActiveMQ 5.x will be supported in Spring 6 and going forward.

Background:

Spring 6 has 'client' support using ActiveMQ's activemq-client-jakarta library (v5.18.2) and waiting for 'server-side' support which will be available in the ActiveMQ 5.19.x release.

The PR for ActiveMQ 5.x Jakarta server-side support is in review and tentatively planned for release in September.

ref: [ActiveMQ 5.x Jakarta PR for server-side support](https://github.com/apache/activemq/pull/996)

ref: [Spring 6 adding ActiveMQ 5.x broker support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34011)

source: I'm the ActiveMQ committer leading the Jakarta migration

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for Spring, but I'm a committer on ActiveMQ and a member of the Project Management Committee for ActiveMQ at Apache. ActiveMQ "Classic" will be supported/maintained for the foreseeable future as it has a large number of existing deployments. Although many folks have migrated (especially as it relates to Spring Boot 3 + Jakarta) many others are either unable or unwilling to make that investment.

Support for ActiveMQ "Classic" was originally removed from Spring Boot 3.0.x due to a lack of support for Jakarta Messaging (which, in turn, requires support for JMS 2). ActiveMQ Artemis was kept because it already had the requisite support on both the client and the broker.

With Spring Boot 3.1.0 ActiveMQ "Classic" support was added back with the following caveats:

- It's client only. The embedded broker is not supported. Support for Jakarta Messaging on the broker is coming via [AMQ-9239](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-9239).
- The client implementation doesn't fully support Jakarta Messaging due to a lack of support for JMS 2. See more details [here](https://activemq.apache.org/jms2).

It's worth noting that development on ActiveMQ "Classic" has slowed a fair bit in the last few years which explains in part why JMS 2 (released 10 years ago in 2013) and Jakarta Messaging (released 3 years ago in 2020) haven't been fully implemented. This, of course, isn't terribly surprising given the development of ActiveMQ Artemis and the fact that it supports both already.